# How to add a line to the Table of Contents without a page number

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, page-numbering, parts

In my LaTeX document, I want to add some extra lines in the Table of Contents to show the general topic of the next section of chapters. The syntax I'm using right now, outlined in a quick example:

```
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter A}
some text
\chapter{Chapter B}
some text
\renewcommand{\thepart}{} %Removes the counting in roman numerals before the part name
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{And now for something completely different} %Adds it to the table of contents without it showing up in the document.
\chapter{Chapter C}
some text
\chapter{Chapter D}
some text
```

However, I want to remove the page number that appears besides the title of 'And now for something completely different' in the Table of Contents. Is there an (easy, preferably without creating your own packages) way to do so?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

instead of `\addcontentsline`, use the more general `\addtocontents` which allows you
to be specific about all parts of a contents line:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\contentsline{part}{And now for something completely different}{}}
```

the final empty group `{}` takes the place of what is usually filled with the page number.

Comment: This doesn't work with hyperref package "Argument of \contentsline has an extra }. \contentsline"

Comment: @Masood_mj seems to stem from `hyperref` package, which overrides that command, according to other posts I read on here.

Comment: To fix the `Argument of \contentsline has an extra}. \contentsline` due to `hyper ref`, see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194720/hyperref-in-toc-without-page-number)