# Incorrect page number counter in beamer using sections

Tags: beamer, sectioning, numbering

I am trying to put together a beamer document put together using multiple sections where frame numbers restart at each section and I can leave certain frames at the beginning of the document and at the beginning of each section uncounted.

My master document looks like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{default} 
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{default} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
 \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
}

\AtBeginSection{\setcounter{framenumber}{0}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\title[MATH]{Daily Notes}
\author{Me}
\institute{My College}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}

{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Table of Contents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\label{ToC}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
}

\input{Day_1.tex}
\input{Day_2.tex}

\end{document}
```

I use hyperref to create links in the table of contents. The two input files are comparable except in the number of frames and that seems to be the trouble. If `Day_1.tex` has 4 frames like so:

```
\section{The First}
\subsection{Housekeeping}

{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Announcements}
Hello world!
\end{frame}
}

\subsection{Content}
\begin{frame}
First slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Second slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Third slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Fourth slide
\end{frame}
```

and `Day_2.tex` is the same except having only 3 frames, then the numbering for Day_1 is given as 1/3, 2/3, 3/3, 4/3. If Day_1 has fewer frames than Day_2 (say 2 for Day_1 and 3 for Day_2), then Day_1's numbering is given as 1/3, 2/3.

How can I get the correct number of frames for each section in the frame numbering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following answer is based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279364/36296

The problem with your approach is that `\totalframenumber` is saved at the end of the document, so in your case it is the length of your last section. But instead you can calculate the length of each section.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcount\beamer@sectionstartframe
\beamer@sectionstartframe=1
\apptocmd{\beamer@section}{\addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{%
            \protect\beamer@sectionframes{\the\beamer@sectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\beamer@section}{\beamer@sectionstartframe=\c@framenumber\advance\beamer@sectionstartframe by1\relax}{}{}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{nav}%
        {\noexpand\headcommand{\noexpand\beamer@sectionframes{\the\beamer@sectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}}{}{}
\def\beamer@startframeofsection{1}
\def\beamer@endframeofsection{1}
\def\beamer@sectionframes#1#2{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber<#1%
    \else%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber>#2%
    \else%
    \gdef\beamer@startframeofsection{#1}%
    \gdef\beamer@endframeofsection{#2}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
}
\newcommand\insertsectionstartframe{\beamer@startframeofsection}
\newcommand\insertsectionendframe{\beamer@endframeofsection}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def\inserttotalsectionframenumber{%
    \pgfmathparse{(\insertsectionendframe-\insertsectionstartframe+1)}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\def\insertsectionframenumber{%
    \pgfmathparse{(\insertframenumber-\insertsectionstartframe+1)}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\insertsectionframenumber/\inserttotalsectionframenumber}

\title[MATH]{Daily Notes}
\author{Me}
\institute{My College}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}

{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Table of Contents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\label{ToC}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
}

\section{The First}
\subsection{Housekeeping}

{
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    \begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Announcements}
        Hello world!
    \end{frame}
}

\subsection{Content}
\begin{frame}
    First slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    Second slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    Third slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    Fourth slide
\end{frame}

\section{The Second}
\subsection{Housekeeping}

{
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    \begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Announcements}
        Hello world!
    \end{frame}
}

\subsection{Content}
\begin{frame}
    First slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    Second slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    Third slide
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @samcarter. This seems like it should work but now I get an error I can't track down: `Argument of \addtocontents has an extra }. <inserted text> \par`

Comment: @Brian Strange. I checked again and I works fine for me. I am on TeXlive2015.

Comment: @Brian Could you solve the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Could it be due to the fact I'm using hyperref, as in (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194720/hyperref-in-toc-without-page-number)?

Comment: Beamer itself should load `hyperref` by default. Can you check if the above code without modifications runs on your system? Or edit your question to show the code you tried?

Comment: I finally tracked down that error. It was caused by the package `nameref` but stopped when I put your fix ahead of loading that package. Thank you so much for your patient help!