# How to define commands before loading the `hyperref` package, which is loaded by my document class?

Tags: errors, hyperref, enumerate, compiling, enumitem

On the question [Missing number, treated as zero when renewing enumerate \item and using hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512546/missing-number-treated-as-zero-when-renewing-enumerate-item-and-using-hyperref) I learned I have to define my custom commands from the question [How to recognize the enumerate shortlabels in my custom environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512413/how-to-recognize-the-enumerate-shortlabels-in-my-custom-environment) before the package `hyperref` to be loaded.

However, my thesis should use the class `abntex2` and the `abntex2` class got the brilliant and extraordinary idea of including the package [`hyperref` on their source code](https://github.com/abntex/abntex2/blob/master/tex/latex/abntex2/abntex2.cls#L126), without any practical reason.

Now, I got no idea how I can include the package `hyperref` after defining my code. So far I tried using `\RequirePackage{enumitem}` and defining my command before loading the `abntex2` class. However, LaTeX threw the error

> enumitem.sty:1587: LaTeX Error: Environment description undefined.

```latex
\PassOptionsToPackage{shortlabels}{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\let\itemenumerateoptional\item
\newcounter{enumerateoptionalcount}

\def\renewenumerateoptionalitem{%
  \let\itemenumerateoptional\item
  \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{%
      \refstepcounter{enumerateoptionali}% increment the counter
      \itemenumerateoptional[\bfseries##1~\theenumerateoptionali]%
  }%
}
\newlist{enumerateoptional}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumerateoptional]{
    before=\renewenumerateoptionalitem,
    label=\arabic*,
    nosep,
    labelindent=20mm,
    leftmargin=*,
    after=\let\item\itemenumerateoptional,
}
\documentclass{abntex2}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerateoptional}[1.]
   \item[Some first] item one
   \item[Some second] item two
\end{enumerateoptional}
\end{document}
```

```
Babel <3.12> and hyphenation patterns for 76 language(s) loaded.
(D:\latex\enumitem.sty

D:\latex\enumitem.sty:1587: LaTeX Error: Environment description undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
D:\latex\enumitem.sty:1587:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

---

Related questions

1. [Using later-defined commands in an own document class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429815/using-later-defined-commands-in-an-own-document-class)
2. [How to override command on my preamble, after its redefinition by my class with renewcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482523/how-to-override-command-on-my-preamble-after-its-redefinition-by-my-class-with)
3. [Hyperref is loaded by the class, and I need to load packages that are supposed to be loaded before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50846/hyperref-is-loaded-by-the-class-and-i-need-to-load-packages-that-are-supposed-t)
4. [when using hyperref package undefined control sequence \chapter error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261954/when-using-hyperref-package-undefined-control-sequence-chapter-error)
5. [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)
6. [Using later-defined commands in an own document class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429815/using-later-defined-commands-in-an-own-document-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine \H@item instead of \item. That should work even if hyperref is loaded too early:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\errorcontextlines 10000
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\def\renewenumerateoptionalitem{%
  \let\itemenumerateoptional\H@item
  \renewcommand{\H@item}[1][]{%
      \refstepcounter{enumerateoptionali}% increment the counter
      \itemenumerateoptional[\bfseries##1~\theenumerateoptionali]%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\newlist{enumerateoptional}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumerateoptional]{
    before=\renewenumerateoptionalitem,
    label=\arabic*,
    nosep,
    labelindent=20mm,
    leftmargin=*,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerateoptional}[1.]
   \item[Some first] item one \label{test}
   \item[Some second] item two
   \item abc
\end{enumerateoptional}
\ref{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Everything works under MikTex on Windows, but when compiling this with Texlive 2017 on Linux, latex says `\ref{test}: Undefined control sequence.`