# How to use package hyperref with template tstextbook

Tags: hyperref

The MWE is the `tstextbook` template:
https://www.typesetters.se/latex-textbook-template/

Inserting `\usepackage{hyperref}` in the preamble of the file `tstextbook.tex` results in error message like so:

```
./tstextbook.mtc1:1: Argument of \contentsline has an extra }
```

I understand that the reason for the error is because `hyperref` redefines `\contentsline` to take four arguments instead of three as referenced here:
[Hyperref in toc without page number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194720/hyperref-in-toc-without-page-number)

If I modify the file `tstextbook.mtc1` and make the first line to equal below:

```
{\reset@font\mtcSfont\mtc@string\contentsline{section}{\noexpand \leavevmode \numberline {1.1}First Section}{\reset@font\mtcSfont 2}{}}
```

... then the new error is

```
./tstextbook.mtc1:2: Argument of \contentsline has an extra }
```

So the solution seems fairly clear, in that the extra brackets need to be inserted.  However, I am still struggling with how/where the `.mtc` files are auto-generated.  Manually changing the `.mtc` files myself is not a permanent fix since the template somehow creates the `.mtc` files automatically.

Bonus points if you can provide a working solution that uses the tstextbook template and hyperlinks the TOC to appropriate pages within the doc, but am happy to post another follow-up question later once the first one here just regarding including the package is resolved.

Comment: Try to delete the auxiliary files and then recompile. If it still breaks: this is a template from a commercial site. So I suggest that you ask their support to debug the template.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to compile `tstextbook.tex` I only  made the following changes to the `tstextbook.cls` to replace two images.

line 50   `contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-A}}}`

line 353  `\marginpar{\vspace{-3mm}\includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{example-image}}}`

Then I addded, before `\begin{document}` a basic `hyperref` setup plus `bookmark`

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,  
pdfpagelabels=true % 
]{hyperref}


\hypersetup{%
    bookmarksnumbered=true,     
    bookmarksopen=true,         
    bookmarksopenlevel=3,   
    colorlinks, 
    breaklinks,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=green, 
    filecolor=black,
    linktocpage=true, 
} 

\RequirePackage{bookmark} % more modern management for bookmarks en pdf
```

After the compilation I found the hyperlinks working properly, to pages in the main TOC and in the individual TOC of the chapters. (color blue)

Also the bookmarks in the pdf.

[image: a]

[image: b]

I did not make changes of any kind to any mtc file.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  The cls image changes are not need, just the preamble works!  BTW what motivated the pic change recommendation? curious

Comment: Because I only downloaded the .tex and .cls files. I didn't want to waste time checking a .zip file from an unknown source. I did it later and it was fine.