# Adding a line in toc without a page number in latex

Tags: table-of-contents

Inside the table of contents of a latex book, I wish to add a few centered horizontal lines, just for typographic clarity (grouping chapters together). If I very naively write something like:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{-----------------------------------}
```

I do get the line in the table of contents, but also an unnecessary page number associated with it; moreover, the line is not centered. How can I insert a centered line into the table of contents without inserting an associated page number?

(I use MiKTeX and WinEdt, but I suppose that this is irrelevant)

Comment: try `\addtocontents{toc}{<stuff>}`

Comment: is it a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152589/how-to-add-a-line-to-the-table-of-contents-without-a-page-number?rq=1?

Answer (score 1):

Although the principal question can be answered with `\addtocontents{toc}{...}`, it's instructive to use the `\leaders` macro to show the repetition of similar characters in the ToC:

The `\mytocline` command expects an argument that should be repeated.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}


\usepackage{pgffor}

\usepackage{tocloft}


\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mytocline}[1]{%
  \hfill\leaders\hbox{$\m@th
    \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{#1}\mkern \@dotsep
    mu$}\hfill
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\foreach \x in {1,...,10} {%
  \section{Foo \x}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\mytocline{$\Sigma\int$}}{}}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]